# Ads for European Economic Area (EEA) (AdMob Android iOS)

Tags: android, ios, admob

In the new rules, you must specify the age for displaying advertising. But there is not a single example of how to do this correctly. What should I ask the user to put the value of `tag_for_under_age_of_consent`? How to do it? Is it enough to show a dialogue? What to ask in the dialogue?
How to behave in the EEA area if I have other advertising providers besides AdMob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Google added instructions:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

Answer (score 2):

There are cases in which you are not always aware of the age of the user. If you want to know whether they are above or below legal age you can use a prompt in which you explicitly state that you need this for advertising purposes. The documentation states:

> If a publisher is aware that the user is under the age of consent, all
>   ad requests must set TFUA (Tag For Users under the Age of Consent in
>   Europe). To include this tag on all ad requests made from your app,
>   call `setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true)`. This setting takes effect for
>   all future ad requests.

Additionally, if you need to handle consent which is related to other networks besides AdMob, Google provides a [library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android) which displays what information is being gathered by the different ad networks. That will ensure that you keep your GDPR compliance. It allows the users to view the different privacy policies of each respective ad network. Hopefully this helps you with solving your issue.